# Permission denied when launching android SDK manager on ubuntu even with root authority

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu, and want to develop android apps with eclipse (because I heard that the android studio can't work very well with NDK stuff yet).

First I installed java-8-oracle with apt-get, it was automatically installed under`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, then I set the environment variables, and executed `java -version` to test if is well installed, everything was fine I even wrote a HelloWorld in java using gedit and ran it in command line ,so there should be nothing wrong with the JDK I think.

But after I installed the eclipse and sdk (extracted frome [adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip) I download), when I opened the eclipse and tried to launch the SDK manager, the problem came like this (eguil is my username):

```
[2015-07-30 10:09:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android: 1: /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Permission denied
[2015-07-30 10:09:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android: 1: /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Permission denied
[2015-07-30 10:09:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android: 110: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Permission denied
```

Then I executed the command

`sudo chmod -R 777 /home/eguil/android`(where the eclipse and SDK are installed)

and

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I assumed that I should never have any "permission problems" from now, but I was wrong, the problem still exists. I'v also tried launching the SDK manager in commond line `sudo ./home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android`, but the output was the same.

Could anyone tell me the reason and how to solve the problem? I'll be appreciated, It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you set the Java environment in ubuntu. Use

```
update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

And you can list JVM(s) available with

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'v already set the environment. Now if I list the available JVM the output is:`java-8-oracle 1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, is that right?

Comment: @Eguil I get `java-8-oracle 1079 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. Anyway, the error `exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Permission denied` is pretty clear. And if you run `file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` you'll see why it *can't* exec it.

Comment: It returned `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: directory`, just shows it's a directory...but if I `ls -l` it, output is `-rwxrwxrwx 1 eguil eguil 3520  July 30 09:55 /home/eguil/android/sdk/tools/android`, it shows that it's all can read write and execute, isn't it?

Comment: @Eguil And how would you execute a directory? Your environment variables aren't set correctly.

Comment: Oh, you remind me... I only thought it was something about the permission issue, it's solved, thanks a lot!